# cache in geowebcache does not update when feature delete or added

Tags: geowebcache

I have Layer with geometry point when I added new point or delete feature point tile in geowebcache does not update if I want to saw updated  tile I must delete folder layer in geoweb cache?
what can I do?
I think that  geowebCahe automatic update when feature modify and tile is updated .is it true?
How can update tile manually in geowebcache?

Comment: Are you using a stand alone GWC or the embeded component within GeoServer?  If the latter, how are you updating the feature?